# Angular HttpClient on API Rest WordPress

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, stackblitz

I had a problem trying to get all my posts from a WordPress API Rest on my angular project.

I'm working on Stack Blitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hj7ofh

This is my API -> http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

and here is my code:

**App Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, PostsComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**and here is the posts.component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any;

  constructor( private data: DataService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data.GetPosts().subscribe(
      data => this.posts = data
      
    );

  }

}
```

and here is the `data.service` where I get the data from the API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class DataService {
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    GetPosts(){
      return this.http.get('http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
    }
   

}
```

and this is the error I get (I don't understand it):

[image]

> ERROR
>
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown
> Error", url: "http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"…}
>
> error: ProgressEvent
>
> headers: HttpHeaders
>
> message: "Http failure response for
> http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts: 0 Unknown Error"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 0
> statusText: "Unknown Error"
> url: "http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
> **proto**: HttpErrorResponse

I'm lost over here! I tried with this API -> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and works! I don't if there is a problem with my API rest http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts but I try with the vanilla JavaScript Fetch and works.

Comment: are you working only on stackblitz? Stackblitz blocks insecure XMLHttpRequest. Your api should be served with `https` instead of `http` if you are planning to work on stackblitz.

Comment: @AJT82 Great observation, IDK about that. Don't you think error message/error should be different in stackblitz console in that case? something understandable?

Comment: @PardeepJain, sure. There should be 2 errors?. At least for me chrome has also always thrown additional error in console ever since started to use Stackblitz in these cases. Other error: `zone.js:3372 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackblitz.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` FF gives a more vague message about mixed content. I'm surprised if OP is not getting some indication of this if indeed only working on Blitz :)

Comment: @AJT82 its strange but even I am not getting the same error you posted in the above comment, This is valid and clear error, and this is what I was expecting the error in the console to be shown. Seriously Man don't know what's happening here.

Comment: Ahh, Got it! I was checking stackblitz console not chrome's console, I believe OP is also checking the same. Chrome's console is showing the exact error. Thanks mate @AJT82

Comment: @PardeepJain, aaaah, didn't even think about Blitz console! But yes, you are probably correct in your assumption :)

Comment: Thanks AJT82 @PardeepJain !!! so the conclusion is to work outside of the Stackblitz or just create the https for my wordpress if I want to keep working on stackblitz?

Comment: @RaulRinconesIzaguirre yes right :)